# which certificate do i need to build an ios app that i created with phonegap?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm creating my application using `Phonegap` and when I'm trying to build the ipa file build `Phonegap` asks me to add a certificate file, and when I'm signing in ios developer I found a certificate for development and a certificate for production and I don't know the good one for me.

so please help

Comment: Do you want to compile your app for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compile your app for testing purposes, you must select certificate to development, you must get UUID of your device where you're going to install your app and add to the list of devices before generate the certificate that way, you will be able to install the app just in these devices.

This tutorial can help you to generate the certificate

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-test-your-app-on-an-ios-device--mobile-13861

Comment: Thank you, i followed this article and it works for me :)